# How to swipe to delete a Card (using appcompat v7's CardView)

Tags: java, android

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:stateListAnimator="@anim/anim"
                                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                                    android:clickable="true"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/textview"
              android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
              android:gravity="center_vertical">

    </TextView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I'm using CardView to display a row of texts. How do I swipe to delete those rows -- which are cardviews? Also, how to set an onItemClickListener for each row? Again, I'm using cardview to display each row.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I wanted to do something similar, so I adapted [romannurik's Android-SwipeToDismiss](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss) to do exactly what we wanted.

[The code is on github](https://github.com/brnunes/SwipeableRecyclerView) with a working sample application, and consists of:

- A subclass of `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` that listens to touch events and detects when an item is being swiped, animating it accordingly.
- A `SwipeListener` that is called in order to know if an item can be dismissed and called again when items are dismissed.

To use it, follow the instructions on github, or just copy the class [`SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener`](https://github.com/brnunes/SwipeableRecyclerView/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/github/brnunes/swipeablerecyclerview/SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.java) to your project and use it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mItems = new ArrayList<>(30);
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        mItems.add(String.format("Card number %2d", i));
    }

    mAdapter = new CardViewAdapter(mItems);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener swipeTouchListener =
            new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener(mRecyclerView,
                    new SwipeableRecyclerViewTouchListener.SwipeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean canSwipe(int position) {
                            return true;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismissedBySwipeLeft(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                mItems.remove(position);
                                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onDismissedBySwipeRight(RecyclerView recyclerView, int[] reverseSortedPositions) {
                            for (int position : reverseSortedPositions) {
                                mItems.remove(position);
                                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
                            }
                            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(swipeTouchListener);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great help. It works but you need to add ```@Override public boolean canSwipeLeft(int position) {return true;}``` and ```@Override public boolean canSwipeRight(int position) {return true;}``` instead of ```@Override public boolean canSwipe(int position) {return true;}```.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the famous Swipe to Dismiss example from Roman Nurik.

https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss

It includes dismissing items in a list and dismissing separate `View`s. It should work on any `View` including `CardView`.

`SwipeDismissListViewTouchListener` is for using in a `ListView` to swipe items. 
`SwipeDismissTouchListener` is for any `View` to dismiss the whole `View` completely.